# MS WORD - Arabic (Quranic) text shown as symbols

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, arabic

I've got an old file that contained Quranic verses in a special Arabic font. Those verses were added using a special software. I'm missing that software, and now when I open the file, all the verses are shown as symbols. Downloading some fonts Arabic/Quranic fonts didn't help.

[image: Here you can see the described problem.]

I greatly appreciate any help.

**EDIT1:**
I've added all Arabic language packs manually to MS Word, but the issue still remains.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvu9w.png)

Comment: Do you have the appropriate Language Pack[s] installed? Win 7 used to add them all automatically [unless you persuaded it not to], but Win 10 doesn't, you need to add them manually.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've added all Arabic language packs, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start is by downloading windows Arabic language pack from Microsoft.
then follow the steps in this link

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-editing-language-or-set-language-preferences-in-office-663d9d94-ca99-4a0d-973e-7c4a6b8a827d

hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've added all the Arabic language packs manually, but the problem still remains.